# Aptana Studio 3.6.1 stand-alone version install error (Win XP and Win 7)

Tags: aptana

I have download Aptana Studio 3.6.1 stand-alone version and attempted to install in on two different computers. The first computer is a Windoxs XP, 32-bit. The second computer is a Windows 7, 64-bit. In each case, I get the same error message about 3-4 minutes into the install:

"Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error."

Any ideas on what I should try?

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you not to use Aptana Studio. It seems that developers are not actively developing it.

I had the same problem, but installing [download nodejs](https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7-x86.msi) solved my problem.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I have no interest in learning an IDE that has been abandoned. I will take a look at Eclipse (open sourced) and PHPStorm (89.00 USD for a year -- for an individual).